# grep multiple extensions in script

Tags: grep

I need to grep in to multiple file extensions that I don't know before hand. So basically,

```
grep -ri --include=\*.{$1} $2 ./
```

Assume that first argument is supplied by the caller of the script. ABove doesn't work however because `{}` is not actually supported by grep by instead is expanded by bash in to multiple --include. Any idea how can I use something like above in script?

Comment: can you give a sample of `$1`? is it multiple or single extension? for single `grep -ri --include='*.'"$1" "$2"` should work...

Comment: for multiple, I think `eval grep -ri --include='*.'{$1} "$2"` might work, but eval  might not be desirable

Comment: Sample that works from command line in terminal: `grep -ri --include=\*.{cmake,txt} "cxx" ./`

Comment: well, can't think of a way other than using `eval` with `$1='cmake,txt'`